# Magento 1.9 - how to recover manually orders from orphaned transactions

Tags: payment-methods, magento1.9.2.3, sagepay

From time to time I'm getting orphaned transaction (Sagepay Suite PRO).
As module developers actually are unable to help sort this out, maybe someone found the way how to recover these orders.

Recovery function mostly does not work (mostly because once or twice only I was able to do it) since then all I'm getting is "The requested Payment Method is not available"..... or other missing elements.

It's a pain in the ....neck, I must chase customers to ask what they actually purchased then create order manually but it is a huge amount of time spent on something we already paid for.

Must say the purchase of this module was like a "shoot in the feet" as Free version was doing exactly the same as "PRO" and same as a "PRO" had this issue.

Mainly that was the reason I bought paid version as they ensure me it will never happen again ...... lie. But at least I can "spam" their support email with hundreds of emails :P.